# Convention for declaring variables in Python, when required for scope?

Tags: python, coding-style, scope

Take this example:

```
def f():
    myvar = None
    def g():
        print myvar

    ...
    myvar = get_real_value()
    g()
```

Is "myvar = None" a conventional (or at least, reasonable) way of declaring the variable, to make it visible to g()? Is there a better way? (Python 2.6.x, if relevant)

Comment: (And yes, I'm certainly aware that I could pass myvar as an argument to g - but let's say there are lots of myvars.)

Comment: Why don't you use simply myvar = ''?. Usually, when myvar is a list, you define it as myvar = [ ], or as myvar = { } if it's a dictionary. Therefore, if myvar is a string, it should be myvar = ''.

Comment: sorry, you're right. in my actual code, it's an object rather than a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to declare the variable before the definition for `g()`:

```
>>> def f():
...     def g():
...         print myvar
...     myvar = 1
...     g()
... 
>>> f()
1
```

However, if you can avoid referencing non-local variables in `g()` that would be preferable, which you would probably do here by having `myvar` be a parameter to `g()`.

Comment: Thanks - strangely, I did test this, but either I'm just confused, or there was something subtly different about the testing I did.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pre-initialize the variable; it only has to be initialized before you call `g()`. Just remove the `myvar = None` line.

For clarity, I prefer to move local functions as close to their point of invocation as practicable, so that the initialisation of local variables that a function uses comes before the function itself.